# Redirect to minified version if is updated via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

There are a way, via `.htaccess` to check if `.css` or `.js` has your own minified version (`.min.css` and `.min.js`, respectively) and redirect to this file, **but** need to have *the same modified time*.

For instance:

```
FILE            MODIFIED TIME
/file.css       01-15-2014T19:28:12
/file.min.css   01-15-2014T19:28:12
/file.js        01-15-2014T19:28:12
/file.min.js    01-15-2014T19:27:47
```

**My idea is**: when someone access the `file.css`, the `.htaccess` will check if `file.min.css` is available and have the same modified time. If yes, it'll returned (via rewrite, redirect), instead of `file.css`.

But, if I access `file.js`, even existing the `file.min.js`, the `.htaccess` will return `file.js` because `file.min.js` is outdated (not have same date/hour).

Is it possible *only* with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first requirement try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if a min version is available then load it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.min.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1.min.$2 [L,NC]
```

However `mod_rewrite` cannot check modification timestamp of your css/js files to make decision based on that. You might need to handle that in your server side code.