# Serve .min.css files first nginx

Tags: css, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I need to configure nginx server.
I have folder with css files there are files some_file.min.css but in html website ask for some_file.css. I need to redirect this request to *min.css and if minified file doesnt exist return normal .css file

```
location ~* \.(css)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $1.min.$2 $uri =404;
        expires 30d;
  }
```

This piece of code does not work.

Comment: if you redirect .css to .min.css it might create 404 error

Comment: I just want to try return .min.css and if this is impossible return normal css file

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148681/redirect-to-minified-version-if-is-updated-via-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the URI into two parts and insert the `.min.` sequence in between. Your `try_files` statement is probably ok, but you have not captured the correct `$1` and `$2` variables.

You need to capture that part of the URI before the `.css`. For example:

```
location ~* ^(.*)\.css$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $1.min.css $uri =404;
    expires 30d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~* ^(.*)(?<!\.min)\.(js|css|html)$ {
    try_files $1.min.$2 $uri =404;
}
```